# Alarm rings, options displayed, then user presses home

Tags: android

I have written an alarm program which works nicely in most regards. When the alarm rings the user is presented with three options to select:

1. Stop
2. Snooze
3. Reschedule

The user then selects their choice, the alarm stops and what happens next depends on which option they selected.

But now I have a problem. Say the alarm goes off and the user accidentally presses the home button whilst fishing their phone out of their pocket. Now the alarm is still ringing, but the app is no longer in display! I don't know how to avoid this scenario. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use activity as dialog, and if home button is pressed causing activity to close,  you can simply put alarm's stop method in onstop()  method of activity.

Comment: But then the user does not get to see what the alarm was for - it may have been to remind the user of a meeting set in the alarm weeks earlier, that the user has forgotten about.

Comment: You can create a notification when alarm goes off

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "create a notification".

Comment: Create notifications like the ones you get from WhatsApp or Google cards, so that every time user turns off alarm by mistakenly pressing home button when alarm strikes, user will still know about it